# How to conditionally aggregate a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with some data that I'm going to run simulations on. Each row is a datetime and a value. Because of the nature of the problem, I need to keep the original frequency of 1 hour when the value is above a certain threshold. When it's not, I could resample the data and run that part of the simulation on lower frequency data, in order to speed up the simulation.

My idea is to somehow group the dataframe by day (since I've noticed there are many whole days where the value stays below the threshold), check the max value over each group, and if the max is below the threshold then aggregate the data in that group into a single mean value.

Here's a minimal working example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

threshold = 3

idx = pd.date_range("2018-01-01", periods=27, freq="H")

df = pd.Series(np.append(np.ones(26), 5), index=idx).to_frame("v")
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                    v
2018-01-01 00:00:00 1.0
2018-01-01 01:00:00 1.0
2018-01-01 02:00:00 1.0
2018-01-01 03:00:00 1.0
2018-01-01 04:00:00 1.0
2018-01-01 05:00:00 1.0
2018-01-01 06:00:00 1.0
2018-01-01 07:00:00 1.0
2018-01-01 08:00:00 1.0
2018-01-01 09:00:00 1.0
2018-01-01 10:00:00 1.0
2018-01-01 11:00:00 1.0
2018-01-01 12:00:00 1.0
2018-01-01 13:00:00 1.0
2018-01-01 14:00:00 1.0
2018-01-01 15:00:00 1.0
2018-01-01 16:00:00 1.0
2018-01-01 17:00:00 1.0
2018-01-01 18:00:00 1.0
2018-01-01 19:00:00 1.0
2018-01-01 20:00:00 1.0
2018-01-01 21:00:00 1.0
2018-01-01 22:00:00 1.0
2018-01-01 23:00:00 1.0
2018-01-02 00:00:00 1.0
2018-01-02 01:00:00 1.0
2018-01-02 02:00:00 5.0
```

The desired output of the operation would be this dataframe:

```
                    v
2018-01-01 00:00:00 1.0
2018-01-02 00:00:00 1.0
2018-01-02 01:00:00 1.0
2018-01-02 02:00:00 5.0
```

where the first value is the mean of the first day.

I think I'm getting close

```
grouped = df.resample("1D")

for name, group in grouped:
    if group["v"].max() <= 3:
        group['v'].agg("mean")
```

but I'm unsure how to actually apply the aggregation to the desired groups, and get a dataframe back.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So I found a solution.

```
grouped = df.resample("1D")
def conditionalAggregation(x):
    if x['v'].max() <= 3:
        idx = [x.index[0].replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)]
        return pd.DataFrame(x['v'].max(), index=idx, columns=['v'])
    else:
        return x

conditionallyAggregated = grouped.apply(conditionalAggregation)
conditionallyAggregated = conditionallyAggregated.droplevel(level=0)
conditionallyAggregated
```

This gives the following df:

```
                    v
2018-01-01 00:00:00 1.0
2018-01-02 00:00:00 1.0
2018-01-02 01:00:00 1.0
2018-01-02 02:00:00 5.0
```

Comment: Kindly explain more what the code does instead of just putting the solution, thanks.

Comment: What part are you unsure about? It solves the problem above, by finding the max over each interval and aggregating if max is above a certain value.